# Marketing Cloud - Email Studio - Query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to fetch **Open Date, Close Date , Email Address , Bounce Category , Email Name** of all subcribers  from **query activity** but the data that I am getting wrong data.Please see the query and let me know that my approch is right or not.

**Query:**

```
SELECT

ea.[first name] as 'First Name',

ea.[last name] as 'Last Name',

s.[EmailAddress] as 'Email',

s.SubscriberKey,

s.SubscriberID,

o.[EventDate] as 'Open Date',

c.[EventDate] as 'Click Date',

j.[EmailName] as 'Email Name',

b.[BounceCategory] as 'Bounce Category',

o.[IsUnique] as 'Unique Opens'

FROM

_subscribers as s with (nolock)

INNER JOIN _EnterpriseAttribute ea with (nolock) ON (s.subscriberID = ea._subscriberID)

INNER JOIN _Open as o with (nolock) ON (s.subscriberID = o.subscriberID)

INNER JOIN _Click as c with (nolock) ON (s.subscriberID = c.subscriberID)

INNER JOIN _Bounce as b with (nolock) ON (s.subscriberID = b.subscriberID)

INNER JOIN _Job as j with (nolock) ON (j.JobID = o.JobID)

WHERE

((o.EventDate >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)

 AND o.EventDate <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0))

OR

(c.EventDate >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)

  AND c.EventDate <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)))
```

Comment: Would generally love to see the purpose of what you are trying to achieve. Fetching Email name + all subscribers doesn't make a lot of sense, as they are data at two different granularity levels - so if you include your goal for the query it will make it a lot easier to provide specific answers :)

Answer (score 3):

The query in question would work - you are joining too many rows of data with potential matches. Below is a revised query that will return one row of data, based on subscribers - not based on a particular job, although you could amend the code to look for that:

```
SELECT
ea.[first name] as 'First Name',
ea.[last name] as 'Last Name',
s.[EmailAddress] as 'Email',
s.SubscriberKey,
s.SubscriberID,
(SELECT MAX(EventDate) FROM _Open o WHERE s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID) AS 'Open Date',
(SELECT MAX(EventDate) FROM _Click c WHERE s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID) AS 'Click Date'

FROM
_subscribers s 
LEFT JOIN _EnterpriseAttribute ea ON s.subscriberID = ea._subscriberID
```

If your goal is to pull data out based on email, the starting point must be different - but please elaborate on your end goal if the above doesn't meet your need.

Also - there is a risk of the above failing, as there may not be any value in _Open or _Clicks, which is why i would typically split it up in multiple sql's.

Comment: How we can compare the subscriber Id   with open and click                                                 (SELECT MAX(EventDate) FROM _Open WHERE **s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID**) AS 'Open Date',
(SELECT MAX(EventDate) FROM _Click WHERE s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID) AS 'Click Date',

Comment: sorry forgot to add the correct letters in front - amended the query to have the right ones now. - and it's not a comparison but a link / join. You are limiting your results by saying you only want the "open records" that matches the subscriber id - and then we select the max value from the returned results.

Comment: I am getting error:                                                                                         **An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. Please use standard syntax.**

Comment: there was a comma at the last select line that shouldn't have been there. I just validated the query (without enterprise attribute) in my own environment. Does it work for you?

Comment: I removed it that comma while implementing the query but still I am getting the error. I want all the fields data of last month that are present in my query. I am getting bounce categories with open and close date which is impossible , if the email is bounce then how we can open or click it.

Comment: This is where you are being mislead by the way your form your data. Based on you what you seek, I would personally create four data extensions - one per system view. One with sent, one with opens, one with clicks and one with bounces. Soft bounces can occur and then the email can still be delivered. Also, given that you use inner join, you are getting only those that exists in all tables - left joins seems more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: I will try left join but I want all the open ,click , bounce data in one data extension.Is it possible to get all the data in same data extension?

Comment: I will create a new answer for that request.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your latest comment, about creating one data extension with all the data i would split it up into four queries. In order to ensure that you get ALL of the data, you would need to create a data extension with the following fields marked as primary key:

- SubscriberKey
- JobId
- EventDate

Create the other necessary fields you reference, "SentDate", "OpenDate", "ClickDate" and "BounceCategory" - the tricky one might be EmailName, but, I'll give my suggestion below in the queries:

**Query 1: _Sent data**

```
SELECT s.SubscriberKey, s.JobId, s.EventDate AS 'Sent Date', j.EmailName AS 'Email Name' , sub.EmailAddress AS 'Email', ea.[first name] as 'First Name', ea.[last name] as 'Last Name' 
FROM _Sent s 
LEFT JOIN _Job j ON s.JobId = j.JobId 
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey 
LEFT JOIN _EnterpriseAttribute ea ON (s.subscriberID = ea._subscriberID) 
WHERE s.EventDate > DateAdd(day,-30, GetDate())
```

If you wish for the operation to replace existing data, so the data extension only contains the last 30 days of data - then you must set this to overwrite

**Query 2: _Open data**

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, JobId, EventDate AS OpenDate
FROM _Open
WHERE EventDate > DateAdd(day,-30, GetDate())
```

This must be an update operation.

**Query 3: _Click data**

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, JobId, EventDate AS ClickDate
FROM _Click
WHERE EventDate > DateAdd(day,-30, GetDate())
```

This must also be an update operation.

**Query 4: _Bounce data**

```
SELECT b.SubscriberKey, b.JobId, b.EventDate AS BounceDate, b.BounceCategory, j.EmailName, sub.EmailAddress AS 'Email', ea.[first name] as 'First Name', ea.[last name] as 'Last Name' 
FROM _Bounce b
LEFT JOIN _Job j ON b.JobId = j.JobId
LEFT JOIN _Subscriber sub ON b.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN _EnterpriseAttribute ea on b.SubscriberId = ea.SubscriberId
WHERE b.EventDate > DateAdd(day,-30, GetDate())
```

This must also be an update operation.

**The data extension configuration based on my queries:**

- SubscriberKey (primary key, string, length 100)
- JobId (primary key, numeric)
- EventDate (date)
- EmailName (string, length 100, nullable)
- Email
- First Name
- Last Name
- OpenDate (date, nullable)
- ClickDate (date, nullable)
- BounceDate (date, nullable)
- BounceCategory (String, length 50, nullable)

**Automation**
The queries must be run using an automation in automation studio, in 4 steps, in the order indicated above.

Comment: Thanks for your described solution. I will try it and let you know but if I also want to fetch First Name , Last Name and email address then in a same way, should I do write another 2 queries on _EnterpriseAttribute and _subscribers?

Comment: One more thing you said Event date mark as primary key, so it is sent Event Date or all 3 Event Dates i.e. sent , open and click.

Comment: Hi kenneth, Your solution is working fine. Thanks a lot.                                     If possible please let me know how to fetch first name ,  last name , email adddress .Should I write 2 more queries on _EnterpriseAttribute and _subscribers in a same way and what are the sequence ?

Comment: Hi Kenneth, Please see and let me know that to fetch first Name, Last Name and email address I updated Sent data query.                            **SELECT s.SubscriberKey, s.JobId, s.EventDate AS 'Sent Date', j.EmailName AS 'Email Name' , sub.EmailAddress AS 'Email', ea.[first name] as 'First Name',
ea.[last name] as 'Last Name'
FROM _Sent s
LEFT JOIN _Job j ON s.JobId = j.JobId
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN _EnterpriseAttribute ea with (nolock) ON (s.subscriberID = ea._subscriberID)
WHERE s.EventDate > DateAdd(day,-30, GetDate())**

Comment: Will look at this tomorrow

Comment: Great - i've amended the bounce query as well, as think you need the revised query to get everything you need :)

Comment: Hi Kenneth, I think there is need of where clause in every query in which I compare jobId , subscriber key and subscriberId to get data correctly.Currently I don't think it updates data correctly because there is no comparision available in open and click query.                                                 One more thing , Can we use inner join in replace of left join?

Comment: We cannot make Sent EventDate as primary key because while updating the oter queries system need Sent EventDate field and tht no available in other queries.

Comment: Hi Vasudha

You're right - it should only be job id as primary key

Comment: And subscriber key

Comment: Hi Kennneth ,Can we use Inner join instead of Left join?

Comment: Is there a reason you want Inter join? I would argue against it, but my immediate reflektion is that it Will make little difference. You Can do a full run with left join, note amount of records, then full run with inner join, and compare differences in record count. If there is a difference, you cannot use inner join

Comment: One more thing, I think we should compare jobId as well as subscriberkey in all queries                                                                                          **SELECT o.SubscriberKey, o.JobId, o.EventDate AS 'Open Date',IsUnique AS 'Unique Opens'
FROM _Open o
LEFT JOIN _Job j ON o.JobId = j.JobId 
LEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub ON o.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey 
LEFT JOIN _EnterpriseAttribute ea ON (o.subscriberID = ea._subscriberID) 
WHERE
o.EventDate > DateAdd(day,-30, GetDate())** and same for click

Comment: Now I have to query on all data views present in query activity.So I am thinking to query on basis of jobId , subscriberkey , SubscriberID

Comment: I Will have to look at this in details, but you shouldn't compare on job id - given that you are doing update calls in subsequent queries. Also, you dont need both subscriberid and subscriberkey - both are static variables :)

Comment: Hi Kenneth, I am trying to query on  Social Network Tracking and Social Network Impressions to update data in same DE but in Social Network Tracking , JobId(primary key) is not present and in Social Network Impressions, Subscribekey(primarykey) is not present.So I am unable to create query.Please give your suggestions on this.

Comment: Please create a new question for social network impressions :)

Comment: hi Vasudha, will you please mark one of the answers as "best answer" so it comes up as "answered" in the search? :) or is there anything outstanding here? :) would love to assist